# How to force printer setup (paper size) in javascript while only printing a div?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing

My project has output with tables that are looping. I need each table to be printed in a 4x6in paper but the js print setup always in letter size. I need tthe print preview to be in the 4x6in format already when clicking the print preview button. Thanks in advance.

I've tried CSS but the javascript isn't adapting the CSS setting.

```
function printDiv(divID) {

    //Get the HTML of div
    var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
    //Get the HTML of whole page
    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

    //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
    document.body.innerHTML =
        "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +
        divElements + "</body>";

    //document.getElementById("pagebreak").style.pageBreakBefore = "always";

    //Print Page
    window.print();

    //Restore orignal HTML
    document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

}
```

Comment: How does this relate to C#? Hint: It doesn't.

Comment: Maybe this [page about Printing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing) will help you? It seems that you should provide a stylesheet for media type `print` to control the layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this stylesheet**

```
<style>
@page 
{
    size:  auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}

html
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the html before sending to printer */
}

body
{
    /*border: solid 1px black ;*/
    margin: 5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm; /* margin you want for the content */
}
</style>
```

Comment: The '@page' says it does not exist in the current context. I'm using asp.net btw

Comment: It does n't have anything to do with asp ... just include the stylesheet in the html page and it should work fine.

Comment: @LiyaWazowski if you use Razor and want to use @Page inline, use `@@Page`